# Estimate Oracle tablespace required before loading data

Tags: oracle-12c, disk-space, tablespaces

I have files ranging from 450 to 750 million rows, which I need to load into our Oracle environment. The DBA asked me to give an estimate on how much tablespace I would need.

How to estimate the required tablespace before loading the data into a table?

Answer (score 1):

There's no magic formula for this. You need to estimate the physical storage required to hold your data, plus (probably) any indexes on that data. That will have as much (or more) to do with the size of the rows as with how many rows of data you have.

Use whatever storage capacity is required for that data now (the size of the existing files) as a ballpark starting point, then be prepared to add more (maybe even a *lot* more) to support Oracle's file header and tablespace free space overhead, indexes, etc.– [pmdba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/203074/pmdba)